# Adding title and author to toc for included pdfs

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, pdfpages, article, author

My former college is starting a departmental journal which I am editing and typesetting. I have edited and typeset every contributed article individually using the `article` class and initially tried to bring them all together using the `combine` class then individually tried the `subfiles` and `standalone` packages but none of it worked.

So finally I decided to use `pdfpages` package and include all the articles as pdfs in my main document.

**Now, each included pdf article has a separate title and author BOTH of which I want to add to the main toc.**

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use option `addtotoc`:

```latex
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={1, section, 1, title -- author, sec:paper1},
]{paper1.pdf}
```